# SMART error on SSD, how can I access data for backup?

Tags: backup, smart

I've got a relatively new Kingston 1TB SSD installed in an Intel NUC running Ubuntu. This is a new build only 2 months old. Upon starting up today I see a S.M.A.R.T. error suggesting I backup and replace the device. Contacted Kingston and I have a new SSD on the way. I managed to boot using the Live USB i used for install so that I could get some diagnostics.

However, I have no way to access the data on the drive to back it up.

Running smartctl shows there is an issue with the drive. I attempted to mount using various superblocks however it appears they are all corrupted. I only need to get the drive into a read only state so I can pull whatever data I can from it.

How can I get a backup from this device as suggested by the SMART message during boot?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl /dev/nvme0n1p1 -x
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-26-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       KINGSTON SA2000M81000G
Serial Number:                      50026B7683CFB158
Firmware Version:                   S5Z42105
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x2646
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x0026b7
Controller ID:                      1
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          1,000,204,886,016 [1.00 TB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            22,138,441,728 [22.1 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            0026b7 683cfb1585
Local Time is:                      Mon Aug 10 10:23:53 2020 UTC
Firmware Updates (0x14):            2 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         32 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     75 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     80 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     9.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     4.60W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     3.80W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0450W       -        -    3  3  3  3     2000    2000
 4 -   0.0040W       -        -    4  4  4  4    15000   15000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
- media has been placed in read only mode

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x08
Temperature:                        25 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    45,116 [23.0 GB]
Data Units Written:                 373,748 [191 GB]
Host Read Commands:                 852,421
Host Write Commands:                3,762,237
Controller Busy Time:               70
Power Cycles:                       45
Power On Hours:                     77
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   22
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    46,979
Error Information Log Entries:      31,278
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 256 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS
  0      31278     1  0x0188  0x0280      -         2856     1     -
  1      31277     1  0x0188  0x0280      -         3112     1     -
  2      31276     1  0x0188  0x0280      -         3112     1     -
  3      31275     1  0x0188  0x0280      -         2856     1     -
  4      31274     1  0x0188  0x0280      -         2856     1     -
  5      31273     1  0x0188  0x0280      -         3112     1     -
  6      31272     1  0x0188  0x0280      -         3112     1     -
  7      31271     1  0x0188  0x0280      -         2856     1     -
  8      31270     1  0x0188  0x0280      -         2856     1     -
  9      31269     1  0x0188  0x0280      -         3112     1     -
 10      31268     1  0x0188  0x0280      -         3112     1     -
 11      31267     1  0x0188  0x0280      -         2856     1     -
 12      31266     1  0x0188  0x0280      -         2600     1     -
 13      31265     1  0x0188  0x0280      -         2600     1     -
 14      31264     1  0x0188  0x0280      -         2600     1     -
 15      31263     1  0x0188  0x0280      -         2600     1     -
... (240 entries not shown)
```

Comment: Can't you boot on the disk ? Or mount it when booting from Live media ?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. I’ve booted onto the USB I used for install and I’m unable to mount either partition. I’ve tried using different superblocks to no avail.

Comment: I have the exact same setup (same SSD model number, also installed on an Intel NUC) and got the same SMART error a few days back. So anyone else coming across this, make sure to keep an eye on your SSD. There might have been a bad batch.

Comment: Update: I successfully RMA'd the SSD and got a new one back. The new one experienced the same issue (SMART errors, read only) after a few months. I have since switched to a Samsung Evo series SSD with no problems whatsoever. No clue what's going on here but I'm done with Kingston SSDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for anyone that stumbles onto this, I did manage to figure it out. You can boot from an Ubuntu Live disk (I used my install USB) and from there use ddrescue to clone the drive onto a backup or replacement disk. I used an external USB drive and managed a full clone which allows me to boot happily. Waiting on the SSD replacement so I can clone back across.

Comment: Once your new disk arrived, did you `dd` the image back onto the new disk? Did you notice any issue on boot afterwards? Or did it just work?

Comment: I used dd and everything worked exactly as before. Even things like Bluetooth and pretty low level changes I made. I was very surprised! I think dd literally does a bit for bit clone. Good luck!